What are we supposed to answer a heretic?
B"H
Pirkei Avos 2:14 says:

Rabbi Elazar would say: Be diligent in the study of Torah. Know what
to answer a heretic. And know before whom you toil, and who is your
employer who will repay you the reward of your labors.
יד רַבִּי אֶלְעָזָר אוֹמֵר: הֱוֵי שָׁקוּד לִלְמוֹד תּוֹרָה. וְדַע מַה
שֶּׁתָּשִׁיב לְאֶפִּיקוּרוּס. וְדַע לִפְנֵי מִי אַתָּה עָמֵל, וּמִי
הוּא בַּֽעַל מְלַאכְתֶּֽךָ שֶׁיְּשַׁלֶּם לָךְ שְׂכַר פְּעֻלָּתֶֽךָ

"Know what to answer a heretic. "
What DO we answer a heretic? Usually there's a concept that one should NOT "answer a fool according to his foolishness, lest one become equal to him."
So what are we supposed to say to a heretic? Does the context matter?

@RaulValdezJr. Yes But the question is on the mishnah
